# Building conda package: built successfully but no source files in it

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am building a conda package for my project by following tutorial at http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html. The structure of my project is as follows:

```
abc-
    conda.recipe-
        bld.bat
        build.sh
        meta.yaml
    sample_data-
        file1.txt
    source-
        code1.py
        code2.py
        setup.py
    tests-
        test.py
    LICENSE
    README.md
```

My meta.yaml file looks like this:

```
package:
  name: abc
  version: "0.1"

source:
  path: ../source/

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - pandas

  run:
    - python
    - pandas
```

bld.bat:

```
"%PYTHON%" setup.py install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

build.sh:

```
$PYTHON setup.py install
```

And setup.py file is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

setup(
    name="abc",
    version='0.1',
    description='some description',
    platforms=["any"],
    install_requires=['pandas']
```

)

I execute the following command to build the package:

```
conda-build abc
```

The package is built successfully and it has two directories named 'info' and 'Lib' but none of them have the code1.py and code2.py files or their executables. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In setup.py, I had to add the following line:

```
packages=find_packages()
```

Package built successfully and included source files after this.